# GnuPG error version 2.0.14

Tags: encryption, gnupg

When i try to encrypt a file using GnuPG the 
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- is added but in the same file the -----END PGP MESSAGE----- is not added in the encrypted file using a java program. When the number of files processed is more this error is noticed. This results in a decryption error

gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: block_filter 0x2656130: read error (size=13663,a->size=13663)

I am using GnuPG version 2.0.14 in Linux environment. Any help on this will be appreciated

Comment: If I understand you correctly, some Java program doesn't give you a valid message. What are you actually asking? 1. Do you want to know how to fix that Java program? If so, you should show the code. 2. Do you want to understand why that GPG error appears? If so, start by showing the inputs and the commands that you typed in *on [su]*. This question appears to be off-topic for [so].

Comment: @Artjom Sorry was not able to explain the problem correctly .The java program we used for testing is available here http://www.macnews.co.il/mageworks/java/gnupg/ (v0.5) this uses Runtime.getRuntime().exec. The encrypted file doesn't contain the End PGP block so it is getting corrupted. The issue happens intermittently and the encrypted file becomes wrong. The issue happens when we have multiple processes doing encryption using the same GnuPG key and is noticed by the testing team. I wanted some pointers on what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a bug in the program. The encrypted file contents was getting truncated. The program uses Runtime. Exec method and was not handling the input stream properly. The issue was not with GnuPG encryption tool.